# How should Tinyproxy be configured to route traffic back to the client properly?

Tags: reverse-proxy, tinyproxy

I'm trying to set up a simple reverse proxy with [Tinyproxy](https://tinyproxy.github.io/).

I'm using something essentially identical as far as I can tell to the default configuration which can be found [here](https://github.com/tinyproxy/tinyproxy/blob/master/etc/tinyproxy.conf.in), posted at the bottom of this question.

When I try to either `curl` or visit `localhost:8888/google/`, I get an empty response. Tinyproxy running in foreground mode shows the following:

```
INFO      Aug 26 20:36:01 [39567]: Initializing tinyproxy ...
INFO      Aug 26 20:36:01 [39567]: Reloading config file
INFO      Aug 26 20:36:01 [39567]: Setting "Via" header to 'tinyproxy'
INFO      Aug 26 20:36:01 [39567]: Added reverse proxy rule: /google/ -> http://www.google.com/
INFO      Aug 26 20:36:01 [39567]: listen_sock called with addr = '(NULL)'
INFO      Aug 26 20:36:01 [39567]: trying to listen on host[::], family[30], socktype[1], proto[6]
INFO      Aug 26 20:36:01 [39567]: listening on fd [5]
INFO      Aug 26 20:36:01 [39567]: trying to listen on host[0.0.0.0], family[2], socktype[1], proto[6]
INFO      Aug 26 20:36:01 [39567]: listening on fd [6]
WARNING   Aug 26 20:36:01 [39567]: Not running as root, so not changing UID/GID.
INFO      Aug 26 20:36:01 [39567]: Creating child number 1 of 10 ...
INFO      Aug 26 20:36:01 [39567]: Creating child number 2 of 10 ...
INFO      Aug 26 20:36:01 [39567]: Creating child number 3 of 10 ...
INFO      Aug 26 20:36:01 [39567]: Creating child number 4 of 10 ...
INFO      Aug 26 20:36:01 [39567]: Creating child number 5 of 10 ...
INFO      Aug 26 20:36:01 [39567]: Creating child number 6 of 10 ...
INFO      Aug 26 20:36:01 [39567]: Creating child number 7 of 10 ...
INFO      Aug 26 20:36:01 [39567]: Creating child number 8 of 10 ...
INFO      Aug 26 20:36:01 [39567]: Creating child number 9 of 10 ...
INFO      Aug 26 20:36:01 [39567]: Creating child number 10 of 10 ...
INFO      Aug 26 20:36:01 [39567]: Finished creating all children.
INFO      Aug 26 20:36:01 [39567]: Setting the various signals.
INFO      Aug 26 20:36:01 [39567]: Starting main loop. Accepting connections.
CONNECT   Aug 26 20:36:04 [39577]: Connect (file descriptor 10): localhost [::1]
CONNECT   Aug 26 20:36:04 [39577]: Request (file descriptor 10): GET /google/ HTTP/1.1
CONNECT   Aug 26 20:36:04 [39577]: Rewriting URL: /google/ -> http://www.google.com/
INFO      Aug 26 20:36:04 [39577]: No upstream proxy for www.google.com
INFO      Aug 26 20:36:04 [39577]: opensock: opening connection to www.google.com:80
```

and `curl` returns `curl: (52) Empty reply from server`

I note that the final line of the logs changes if I change the route for google.com to `https`. In this case, I get:

```
INFO      Aug 26 20:37:45 [39616]: No upstream proxy for localhost
INFO      Aug 26 20:37:45 [39616]: opensock: opening connection to localhost:8888
```

The config is as follows:

```
##
## tinyproxy.conf -- tinyproxy daemon configuration file
##
## This example tinyproxy.conf file contains example settings
## with explanations in comments. For decriptions of all
## parameters, see the tinproxy.conf(5) manual page.
##

#
# User/Group: This allows you to set the user and group that will be
# used for tinyproxy after the initial binding to the port has been done
# as the root user. Either the user or group name or the UID or GID
# number may be used.
#
User nobody
Group nobody

#
# Port: Specify the port which tinyproxy will listen on.  Please note
# that should you choose to run on a port lower than 1024 you will need
# to start tinyproxy using root.
#
Port 8888

#
# Listen: If you have multiple interfaces this allows you to bind to
# only one. If this is commented out, tinyproxy will bind to all
# interfaces present.
#
#Listen 192.168.0.1

#
# Bind: This allows you to specify which interface will be used for
# outgoing connections.  This is useful for multi-home'd machines where
# you want all traffic to appear outgoing from one particular interface.
#
#Bind 192.168.0.1

#
# BindSame: If enabled, tinyproxy will bind the outgoing connection to the
# ip address of the incoming connection.
#
#BindSame yes

#
# Timeout: The maximum number of seconds of inactivity a connection is
# allowed to have before it is closed by tinyproxy.
#
Timeout 600

#
# ErrorFile: Defines the HTML file to send when a given HTTP error
# occurs.  You will probably need to customize the location to your
# particular install.  The usual locations to check are:
#   /usr/local/share/tinyproxy
#   /usr/share/tinyproxy
#   /etc/tinyproxy
#
#ErrorFile 404 "@pkgdatadir@/404.html"
#ErrorFile 400 "@pkgdatadir@/400.html"
#ErrorFile 503 "@pkgdatadir@/503.html"
#ErrorFile 403 "@pkgdatadir@/403.html"
#ErrorFile 408 "@pkgdatadir@/408.html"

#
# DefaultErrorFile: The HTML file that gets sent if there is no
# HTML file defined with an ErrorFile keyword for the HTTP error
# that has occured.
#
DefaultErrorFile "@pkgdatadir@/default.html"

#
# StatHost: This configures the host name or IP address that is treated
# as the stat host: Whenever a request for this host is received,
# Tinyproxy will return an internal statistics page instead of
# forwarding the request to that host.  The default value of StatHost is
# @TINYPROXY_STATHOST@.
#
#StatHost "@TINYPROXY_STATHOST@"
#

#
# StatFile: The HTML file that gets sent when a request is made
# for the stathost.  If this file doesn't exist a basic page is
# hardcoded in tinyproxy.
#
StatFile "@pkgdatadir@/stats.html"

#
# LogFile: Allows you to specify the location where information should
# be logged to.  If you would prefer to log to syslog, then disable this
# and enable the Syslog directive.  These directives are mutually
# exclusive. If neither Syslog nor LogFile are specified, output goes
# to stdout.
#
#LogFile "@localstatedir@/log/tinyproxy/tinyproxy.log"

#
# Syslog: Tell tinyproxy to use syslog instead of a logfile.  This
# option must not be enabled if the Logfile directive is being used.
# These two directives are mutually exclusive.
#
#Syslog On

#
# LogLevel: Warning
#
# Set the logging level. Allowed settings are:
#   Critical    (least verbose)
#   Error
#   Warning
#   Notice
#   Connect     (to log connections without Info's noise)
#   Info        (most verbose)
#
# The LogLevel logs from the set level and above. For example, if the
# LogLevel was set to Warning, then all log messages from Warning to
# Critical would be output, but Notice and below would be suppressed.
#
LogLevel Info

#
# PidFile: Write the PID of the main tinyproxy thread to this file so it
# can be used for signalling purposes.
# If not specified, no pidfile will be written.
#
#PidFile "@localstatedir@/run/tinyproxy/tinyproxy.pid"

#
# XTinyproxy: Tell Tinyproxy to include the X-Tinyproxy header, which
# contains the client's IP address.
#
#XTinyproxy Yes

#
# Upstream:
#
# Turns on upstream proxy support.
#
# The upstream rules allow you to selectively route upstream connections
# based on the host/domain of the site being accessed.
#
# Syntax: upstream type (user:pass@)ip:port ("domain")
# Or:     upstream none "domain"
# The parts in parens are optional.
# Possible types are http, socks4, socks5, none
#
# For example:
#  # connection to test domain goes through testproxy
#  upstream http testproxy:8008 ".test.domain.invalid"
#  upstream http testproxy:8008 ".our_testbed.example.com"
#  upstream http testproxy:8008 "192.168.128.0/255.255.254.0"
#
#  # upstream proxy using basic authentication
#  upstream http user:pass@testproxy:8008 ".test.domain.invalid"
#
#  # no upstream proxy for internal websites and unqualified hosts
#  upstream none ".internal.example.com"
#  upstream none "www.example.com"
#  upstream none "10.0.0.0/8"
#  upstream none "192.168.0.0/255.255.254.0"
#  upstream none "."
#
#  # connection to these boxes go through their DMZ firewalls
#  upstream http cust1_firewall:8008 "testbed_for_cust1"
#  upstream http cust2_firewall:8008 "testbed_for_cust2"
#
#  # default upstream is internet firewall
#  upstream http firewall.internal.example.com:80
#
# You may also use SOCKS4/SOCKS5 upstream proxies:
#  upstream socks4 127.0.0.1:9050
#  upstream socks5 socksproxy:1080
#
# The LAST matching rule wins the route decision.  As you can see, you
# can use a host, or a domain:
#  name     matches host exactly
#  .name    matches any host in domain "name"
#  .        matches any host with no domain (in 'empty' domain)
#  IP/bits  matches network/mask
#  IP/mask  matches network/mask
#
#Upstream http some.remote.proxy:port

#
# MaxClients: This is the absolute highest number of threads which will
# be created. In other words, only MaxClients number of clients can be
# connected at the same time.
#
MaxClients 100

#
# MinSpareServers/MaxSpareServers: These settings set the upper and
# lower limit for the number of spare servers which should be available.
#
# If the number of spare servers falls below MinSpareServers then new
# server processes will be spawned.  If the number of servers exceeds
# MaxSpareServers then the extras will be killed off.
#
MinSpareServers 5
MaxSpareServers 20

#
# StartServers: The number of servers to start initially.
#
StartServers 10

#
# MaxRequestsPerChild: The number of connections a thread will handle
# before it is killed. In practise this should be set to 0, which
# disables thread reaping. If you do notice problems with memory
# leakage, then set this to something like 10000.
#
MaxRequestsPerChild 0

#
# Allow: Customization of authorization controls. If there are any
# access control keywords then the default action is to DENY. Otherwise,
# the default action is ALLOW.
#
# The order of the controls are important. All incoming connections are
# tested against the controls based on order.
#
Allow 127.0.0.1
Allow ::1

# BasicAuth: HTTP "Basic Authentication" for accessing the proxy.
# If there are any entries specified, access is only granted for authenticated
# users.
#BasicAuth user password

#
# AddHeader: Adds the specified headers to outgoing HTTP requests that
# Tinyproxy makes. Note that this option will not work for HTTPS
# traffic, as Tinyproxy has no control over what headers are exchanged.
#
#AddHeader "X-My-Header" "Powered by Tinyproxy"

#
# ViaProxyName: The "Via" header is required by the HTTP RFC, but using
# the real host name is a security concern.  If the following directive
# is enabled, the string supplied will be used as the host name in the
# Via header; otherwise, the server's host name will be used.
#
ViaProxyName "tinyproxy"

#
# DisableViaHeader: When this is set to yes, Tinyproxy does NOT add
# the Via header to the requests. This virtually puts Tinyproxy into
# stealth mode. Note that RFC 2616 requires proxies to set the Via
# header, so by enabling this option, you break compliance.
# Don't disable the Via header unless you know what you are doing...
#
#DisableViaHeader Yes

#
# Filter: This allows you to specify the location of the filter file.
#
#Filter "@pkgsysconfdir@/filter"

#
# FilterURLs: Filter based on URLs rather than domains.
#
#FilterURLs On

#
# FilterExtended: Use POSIX Extended regular expressions rather than
# basic.
#
#FilterExtended On

#
# FilterCaseSensitive: Use case sensitive regular expressions.
#
#FilterCaseSensitive On

#
# FilterDefaultDeny: Change the default policy of the filtering system.
# If this directive is commented out, or is set to "No" then the default
# policy is to allow everything which is not specifically denied by the
# filter file.
#
# However, by setting this directive to "Yes" the default policy becomes
# to deny everything which is _not_ specifically allowed by the filter
# file.
#
#FilterDefaultDeny Yes

#
# Anonymous: If an Anonymous keyword is present, then anonymous proxying
# is enabled.  The headers listed are allowed through, while all others
# are denied. If no Anonymous keyword is present, then all headers are
# allowed through.  You must include quotes around the headers.
#
# Most sites require cookies to be enabled for them to work correctly, so
# you will need to allow Cookies through if you access those sites.
#
#Anonymous "Host"
#Anonymous "Authorization"
#Anonymous "Cookie"

#
# ConnectPort: This is a list of ports allowed by tinyproxy when the
# CONNECT method is used.  To disable the CONNECT method altogether, set
# the value to 0.  If no ConnectPort line is found, all ports are
# allowed.
#
# The following two ports are used by SSL.
#
# ConnectPort 443
# ConnectPort 563

#
# Configure one or more ReversePath directives to enable reverse proxy
# support. With reverse proxying it's possible to make a number of
# sites appear as if they were part of a single site.
#
# If you uncomment the following two directives and run tinyproxy
# on your own computer at port 8888, you can access Google using
# http://localhost:8888/google/ and Wired News using
# http://localhost:8888/wired/news/. Neither will actually work
# until you uncomment ReverseMagic as they use absolute linking.
#
ReversePath "/google/"  "https://www.google.com/"
#ReversePath "/wired/"  "http://www.wired.com/"

#
# When using tinyproxy as a reverse proxy, it is STRONGLY recommended
# that the normal proxy is turned off by uncommenting the next directive.
#
ReverseOnly Yes

#
# Use a cookie to track reverse proxy mappings. If you need to reverse
# proxy sites which have absolute links you must uncomment this.
#
ReverseMagic Yes

#
# The URL that's used to access this reverse proxy. The URL is used to
# rewrite HTTP redirects so that they won't escape the proxy. If you
# have a chain of reverse proxies, you'll need to put the outermost
# URL here (the address which the end user types into his/her browser).
#
# If not set then no rewriting occurs.
#
ReverseBaseURL "http://localhost:8888/"
```

So, the question is, what part of the config is incorrect here and what needs to change to have traffic route correctly through?

Answer (score 0):

Set max clients to 10000 and try again. 500 should be ok